# Prove that certain amount of data was stored

Tags: reference-request, zero-knowledge-proofs, proof-of-work

I'm looking for a way to prove that a certain amount of data was stored, through some easily verifiable piece of information. Similarly to how proof-of-work can prove through a hash that a certain amount of work was done to generate such hash.

I don't need this "proof" to tell me whether that data is *currently* stored somewhere, I'm just interested in proving that a certain amount of data was stored (anytime in the past) via some sort of hash or other piece of information.

For instance, imagine I have to prove to someone that I was able to store 5 GB. Doesn't matter where, I could use many different computers. One requirement I guess is that the proof should be easy to validate.

Any ideas?

Comment: related http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15178/proof-of-storage-scheme?rq=1

Comment: http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/805.pdf $\;$

Answer (score 1):

Proof of Storage is what you are looking for (also called Proof of Data Possession). The timestamp will prove that the data was stored at a certain time, as per your question.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_space):

> ...instead of showing that space is available for solving a puzzle,
> the prover shows that space is actually used to store a piece of data
> correctly at the time of proof.

See [Storj](https://www.storj.io/), which is decentralized cloud storage.

The concept of Proof of Existence is another way.  In Blockchain, it is done by cryptographic hashing. The amount of data and a time stamp are hashed and added to the public distributed ledger.

> Simply by a process of Blockchain registering and timestamping, Proof
> of Existence enables anyone to anonymously and securely store an
> online distributed proof of existence for any document. Documents are
> not stored in a centralized database or in the Bitcoin Blockchain, so
> all data stays private. All that is stored is a cryptographic digest
> of the file, linked to the time in which the document was submitted.

Proof of Capacity (space is available for solving a puzzle) is another concept used in Blockchain, but this is merely related to what you are looking for.  Basically, you allocate disk space and then prove that you have done so.  [Burstcoin (Signum)](https://www.burst-coin.org/index.html) uses this.